# Is it possible to award a bounty to or otherwise reward an exceptional answer?

Tags: discussion, bounties

If I pose a question and receive a number of responses to it, I can obviously upvote answers and accept an answer. Is there a mechanism for awarding special recognition to an exceptional answer? I have in mind setting a bounty and immediately awarding it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manually award a bounty to any answer; however, you must wait a bit (a day?) after setting the bounty before awarding it.

Comment: If you're worried about unfairly holding out a carrot to new answers while you wait that day, you could put a comment on the answer explaining the bounty (and perhaps delete that later).  In fact, for older questions that are seemingly answered, it's probably always a good idea to leave some similar kind of comment.

Comment: You also [cannot award a small bounty to an answer if the question already had a larger bounty on it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142163/136714).