# Award extra points to answer?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

I must have been dreaming, but I could have sworn one was able to award extra reputation points to answers on stackoverflow.com if you felt the answer deserved it.

I'm in this predicament right now, where I was too late with choosing the best answer for a bounty question. I still want to award the answerer the full points, but I can't find the damn option to award extra rep. points anymore. :-/

Have I been imagining this 'extra rep. points' thing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only way to award extra rep than a simple upvote is to award a bounty, or accept the answer.

As of now, (besides the bounty) there is no way to freely 'gift' reputation.

Comment: That's not *entirely* true: Bounties can be considered 'gifting' reputation.  The FAQ for bounties even points out this as a feature of the bounty... feature.

Comment: @George, I re-phrased. I don't think of bounty as a gift.  I think of it as paid work.

Comment: LOL. I get it.

Comment: it would be great to be able to gift some points on the spot, say 10, 20 or 50. The bounty system could be used but is cumbersome and confusing in that case.

Comment: I guess there is not way to add bounty "retroactively", correct? Meaning someone already answered but was very helpful... some kind of reddit gold basically...

Answer (score 5):

In older versions of the stackexchange software points could be awarded to the answers, this does not appear to be an option anymore.

Answer (score 3):

As Justin mentioned, there is no 'gift rep'.

If you want to further reward an answer check out this question: [Is it possible to award a bounty to or otherwise reward an exceptional answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69592/is-it-possible-to-award-a-bounty-to-or-otherwise-reward-an-exceptional-answer).

Also, if you can move the accepted answer and post a link to the question which will give it more publicity and therefore possibly more upvotes to the good answer.