# Super Answer Bonus Points?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Award extra points to answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77226/award-extra-points-to-answer)

Occasionally I post obscure questions on SE.  My thought is that there is probably a guru out there who has at least seen or heard of an experience like mine and they may one day stumble upon my question.  Furthermore, someone else may run into the same issue.  The Stack Exchange network is well indexed on Google so my intent  is that my question will show up for the person who one day may run into the same issue that I've had when they try to google for a solution.

These questions often get answered after a few weeks or months and within the pool of obscure questions that I've asked, I occasionally get an answer that is extremely thorough and goes above and beyond my expectation of an adequate answer.  These super-answers often receive numerous up-votes on common questions but for the obscure ones, they may only receive one, or two up-votes, even though they exhibit an large amount of expertise from the answerer.

Since these questions deserve a better reward, I'd like to suggestion a feature that can allow question askers to give bonus-points to their answerers.  These bonus-points should be like bounty points being that they come directly from the askers reputation.  Also, I don't think the values should be as high as bounties.  A list of options such as `5, 10, 25, 50` would seem like a fair amount of options for bonus point assignments.

I'm not sure if this has been suggested before.  If it has, please link to the discussion because I'd like to either understand the justification for not implementing this feature, or weigh in, with examples, of times that I feel that this has seemed appropriate.

Comment: You can actually use bounties for this =)  There is a bounty reason specifically for rewarding exceptional answers.

Comment: Oh... I hadn't noticed that.  :(  *sigh*, please close the question.

Comment: 25 bonus points = upvote + accepted answer. Also, if it's marked as helpful enough by anonymous users, it automatically gets a bounty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a bounty for this. If you are awarding a bounty, you can use this option

> **Reward existing answer**
>
> One or more of the answers is exemplary and
>   worthy of an additional bounty.

For more information on the bounty system you can check out: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Hey, [that's what I said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122996/super-answer-bonus-points#comment327469_122996)!  +1 to you =)

Comment: Jah, I was slow :). I wanted to add the link, but I'm a klutz at finding the right FAQ questions. I always press the FAQ button on top, then remembering that it's more META then I need, so, I search for the FAQ, and not the FAQ-about the Questions (iykwim)... :D

Comment: Haha, I follow you =)  Your answer is much more thorough than my comment, so that's a good thing.

Comment: +1 I didn't know this! Was about to ask the same question as I was being given the bonus bounty and didn't know whether it was allowed in SO.