# Spend reputation for good answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to spend some reputation for a particularly good answer? Sometimes I would like to say thank you by not just commenting. :-)

A workaround is to create a bounty, but that's not exactly what I'm after.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239088/provide-a-means-to-reward-users-and-their-answers-decoupled-from-bounties http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122996/super-answer-bonus-points http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77226/award-extra-points-to-answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74486/promoting-the-answer-with-extra-up-voting

Answer (score 3):

This is actually one of the reasons for a bounty:

[image: Bounty reasons]

Alternately, there's the free option of upvoting... you pay nothing, they get ten rep it's win-win.

---

Also, [please don't say "thanks" in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;

Comment: I've heard about this upvoting thing before... care to explain?

Comment: @pfnuesel this is not upvoting, it's giving away a bounty. Bounties are explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).