# Extra bounty for questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Award extra points to answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77226/award-extra-points-to-answer)

**1.** Bounties are a great encouragement for us to work around a featured question, giving it extra attention and views. User who posted the accepted answer gets reputation value as set inside the bounty. But sometimes, there may be more answers, which are very helpful and useful, or may be pointing towards accomplishing the same task (done by the accepted answer), but in another way or route. Upvotes are helpful in this case giving them +10 rep. But if someone else found the answer very helpful for him, he may be willing to give the answer more than just +10. In this case, a custom rep feature, that any user who found some answer great, can award to that answer will encourage users more.
**I GOT THIS** in @Bart's answer.

But,

**2.** It will be fine if this facility is available to the questions also, giving some custom rep to the user who asked question, if someone found the question useful, which led to great answers (only great questions can help develop great answers), more than just an upvote, which gives the user +5.

Comment: This is already in place. You can already award a bounty to a specific answer.

Comment: @Bart how can i do that?

Comment: [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: But this happens only for question already having a bounty. I am talking about giving answers a custom rep (no matter whether question have bounty or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer your first question**:
You can already award a bounty to an answer. Simply go to the question, start a bounty, select the amount of rep you want to donate. You will then be presented with the following popup:

[image]

As you can see, the very last option allows you to reward an existing answer which you deem worthy of an additional bounty.

**To answer your second question**:
I'm not sure that that particular option exists, but there are several options already.

Things that come to mind are to add a general bounty to the question. The extra attention might get the OP some additional upvotes. And who knows, there might be an additional great answer as well, which would be a welcome bonus.

Otherwise you could always reward a particularly good answer the OP gave to another question.

Comment: In fact, this way the answer will also get an additional reward - the question appears in the "featured" list which typically generated upvotes for existing answers.

Comment: good. and what about bounty award to the user who asked question